# Why is doctrine rejecting my foreign key constraint?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I'm attempting to add a many-to-one relationship between fields in two doctrine entities. I have a facebook feed table, which lists facebook feeds and their corresponding facebook IDs, and I have a FbPageLikes entity, which is a table where I record rows of the number of likes for these facebook feeds over time.

I believe I have annotated correctly, yet I still see this error when attempting to migrate: `General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint`

Is there something wrong with my annotations? How can I debug this doctrine migration?

FbPageLikes entity:

```
 /**
 * @var $facebookId
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Feed", inversedBy="fbPageLikes")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="facebook_id", referencedColumnName="facebookId", onDelete="CASCADE")
 * })
 */
private $facebookId;
```

Feed entity:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="facebookId", type="bigint", nullable=true)
 */
private $facebookId;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="FbPageLikes", mappedBy="facebookId", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
 */
private $fbPageLikes;
```

Comment: Something to check with this message: make sure you have created the tables that you refer to first.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I checked, and they're definitely there.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this setup failed was because of the annotations on the `FbPageLikes` entity. The `referencedColumnName` field must refer the the primary key in the corresponding entity `Feed`. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-joincolumn

In my case, I had to set `referencedColumnName` to refer to the `id` column of the `Feed` entity, instead of to the `facebookId` column.